# Touchpad not working in login screen

Tags: 18.04, touchpad, login-screen

I have an Asus x507 laptop. I'm using Ubuntu 18.04 everything working fine; but, the touchpad is not working on the login screen. I have changed default Ubuntu dwm to Cinnamon's login screen that I'm using now.

How can I get my touchpad to work with dwm?